# addthis share button don't display images

Tags: javascript, share, addthis

I don't know whether is it right or not to ask this question. But I've been facing problems with share buttons that I got from addthis.com . addthis.com provided me the following code to add to my website

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52a877a15b8d59d4"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

The share buttons are displayed (you can see [here](http://viewsnepal.com/np/display-content.php?id=96#.UqiYcdIW1vD)). But when i hit the share button, the title and description on the news is displayed but the corresponding image of the news is not displayed in the share dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the following page. It might help you.

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381222-optimize-facebook-sharing#.UqihM_RdXrc

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.org/path/to/your/image.jpg"/>
```